# MLOps with TFX: How to ingest data when using Sequence from Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tfx, tensorflow-extended

I am using a class called `DataGenerator`, that returns a tuple `(data_array, label_array)`, follows the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    """
    path_data: the path of the csv files
    """
...
```

This class consumes from a list of `.csv` files, as shown in the following image:

[image]

Each file contains a column like this:

```
0.44
0.45
0.42
0.22
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.11
0.11
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.05
```

But these files are very huge and each one represents the data of each instance.

The problem is that I don't understand how to ingest the data through the `tfx.v1.components.CsvExampleGen` to use it inside the `tfx` pipeline...

- Is it possible to ingest the data using `tfx` or should I look at another alternative?
- Can I use CsvExampleGen to ingest from a bunch of files in a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Data ingestion which consists of reading data from raw format and formatting it into a binary format suitable for ML (e.g. TFRecord). TFX provides a standard component called [ExampleGen](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/guide/examplegen.md) which is responsible for generating training examples from different data sources.

[tfx.v1.components.CsvExampleGen](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/api_docs/python/tfx/v1/components/CsvExampleGen) component takes `input_base` args which expects an external directory containing the CSV files. You can even customize the input and output train/eval split ratio for ExampleGen as shown [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/docs/guide/examplegen.md#custom-inputoutput-split).

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have five features, and that initially their shapes are (None, 1), and you need them to be a higher-dimensional feature of shape (None, 1, 5) when you are done?  In my mind, this is doable with tfx, you would need to concatenate your data in the `Transform` component using the right axis after reading with `CsvExampleGen`.  If you could clarify how `DataGenerator` gets the data, maybe there is a simpler solution.